# SessionSecurityToken is always null

Tags: wif

I have a sample asp.net website that talks to a custom sts for login. I can login to the site with sts, but when I am at the site, and hit refresh, it goes to an infinite loop between sts and the site itself.
When I use reflector pro and check WIF dll, it seems that SessionSecurityToken is always null.
Does anybody experience the same issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check cookies settings in your browser.

Comment: I dont understand why it can't write the cookie. I try to use reflector pro to debug SessionAuthModule, it seems that it has an issue with cookie lifetime?

Answer (score 2):

Issue could be because of Logon Token expiration
check here
http://www.anmolrehan-sharepointconsultant.com/2011/06/security-token-service-sts-and.html